# Latex-preview not working; Please adjust ‘dvisvgm’ part of ‘org-preview-latex-process-alist’

Tags: org-mode, preview-latex

i have a strange problem with latex-preview.
If the cursor is inside

```
\begin{equation}
   \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = \binom{n}{k} 
\end{equation}
```

then the tex file is created and a resulting pdf.
BUT no svg file and no preview.

the resulting log-file does not contain any special, as far as i see.

```
    This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020)  (format=lualatex 2020.11.8)  15 MAR 2021 19:34
 restricted system commands enabled.
**/tmp/orgtexlLgQbd.tex
(/tmp/orgtexlLgQbd.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
Lua module: luaotfload-main 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload entry point
Lua module: luaotfload-init 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / initializatio
n
Lua module: lualibs 2020-02-02 2.70 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2020-02-02 2.70 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
Lua module: luaotfload-log 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / logging
Lua module: luaotfload-parsers 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / filelist
Lua module: luaotfload-configuration 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / conf
ig file reader
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "/home/held/.texlive2020/texmf-var/l
uatex-cache/generic-dev/names".
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2020-05-06.lua" from kpse-res
olved path "/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-2020-
05-06.lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 2
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@syllabe = 3
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version 0x1.8e353f7ced917p+1
Lua module: luaotfload-fallback 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / fallback
Lua module: luaotfload-multiscript 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / multis
cript
Lua module: luaotfload-script 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / Script help
ers
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Lua module: luaotfload-loaders 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / callback h
andling
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Lua module: luaotfload-database 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / database
Lua module: luaotfload-unicode 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / Unicode he
lpers
Lua module: luaotfload-colors 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 4
Lua module: luaotfload-resolvers 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / resolver
s
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "/home/held/.texlive2020/texmf-var/l
uatex-cache/generic-dev/names".
Lua module: luaotfload-features 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / features
Lua module: luaotfload-harf-define 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / databa
se
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' at position 1 in `find_opentype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' at position 1 in `find_truetype_file'.
Lua module: luaotfload-harf-plug 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / database
Inserting `Harf pre_output_filter callback' at position 1 in `pre_output_filter'
.
Inserting `Harf wrapup_run callback' at position 1 in `wrapup_run'.
Inserting `Harf finish_pdffile callback' at position 1 in `finish_pdffile'.
Inserting `Harf glyph_info callback' at position 1 in `glyph_info'.
Lua module: luaotfload-letterspace 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-embolden 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-notdef 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-suppress 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / suppress
Lua module: luaotfload-szss 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-auxiliary 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / auxiliar
y functions
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' at position 5 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Lua module: luaotfload-tounicode 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / tounicod
e
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 6 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
. L3 programming layer <2020-04-06>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from /home/held/.texlive2020/texmf-
var/luatex-cache/generic-dev/names/luaotfload-names.luc)
\c@part=\count163
\c@section=\count164
\c@subsection=\count165
\c@subsubsection=\count166
\c@paragraph=\count167
\c@subparagraph=\count168
\c@figure=\count169
\c@table=\count170
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
Package: color 2019/11/23 v1.2a Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package color Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 147.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def
File: luatex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for luatex
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2020-04-06 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def
File: l3backend-pdfmode.def 2020-03-12 L3 backend support: PDF mode
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count171
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box45
))
Package: xparse 2020-03-06 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count172
\g__xparse_grabber_int=\count173
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count174
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count175
)
Package: fontspec 2020/02/21 v2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
Lua module: fontspec 2020/02/21 2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
Package: fontspec-luatex 2020/02/21 v2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count176
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count177
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count178
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count179
\l__fontspec_tmpa_int=\count180
\l__fontspec_tmpb_int=\count181
\l__fontspec_tmpc_int=\count182
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count183
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count184
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count185
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count186
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen135
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen136
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen137

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2020/02/11 v2.0o Standard LaTeX package
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2019/11/30 v1.2a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2019/11/30 v1.4a Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 105.
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen138
\Gin@req@width=\dimen139
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/grffile/grffile.sty
Package: grffile 2019/11/11 v2.1 Extended file name support for graphics (legacy
)
Package grffile Info: This package is an empty stub for compatibility on input l
ine 40.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ulem/ulem.sty
\UL@box=\box46
\UL@hyphenbox=\box47
\UL@skip=\skip49
\UL@hook=\toks16
\UL@height=\dimen140
\UL@pe=\count187
\UL@pixel=\dimen141
\ULC@box=\box48
Package: ulem 2019/11/18
\ULdepth=\dimen142
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2020/01/20 v2.17e AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip50

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks17
\ex@=\dimen143
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen144
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count188
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 227.
\uproot@=\count189
\leftroot@=\count190
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 389.
\classnum@=\count191
\DOTSCASE@=\count192
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 486.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 489.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 610.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box49
\strutbox@=\box50
\big@size=\dimen145
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 733.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 734.
\macc@depth=\count193
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count194
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count195
\dspbrk@lvl=\count196
\tag@help=\toks18
\row@=\count197
\column@=\count198
\maxfields@=\count199
\andhelp@=\toks19
\eqnshift@=\dimen146
\alignsep@=\dimen147
\tagshift@=\dimen148
\tagwidth@=\dimen149
\totwidth@=\dimen150
\lineht@=\dimen151
\@envbody=\toks20
\multlinegap=\skip51
\multlinetaggap=\skip52
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks21
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2859.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2860.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
Package: textcomp 2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
))
No file orgtexlLgQbd.aux.

\openout1 = orgtexlLgQbd.aux
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 31
.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 31.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count266
\scratchdimen=\dimen152
\scratchbox=\box51
\nofMPsegments=\count267
\nofMParguments=\count268
\everyMPshowfont=\toks22
\MPscratchCnt=\count269
\MPscratchDim=\dimen153
\MPnumerator=\count270
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count271
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks23
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 48
5.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live

))

Package fontspec Info: Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid
(fontspec)             this).

\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup6
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  TU/lmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> TU/lmr/m/it on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/lmr/b/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> TU/lmss/m/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/m/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/lmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/b/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> TU/lmr/b/it on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> TU/lmss/b/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/b/n on input line 31.
\GPT@outputbox=\box52
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msa on input line 38.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msb on input line 38.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
) [1

{/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (/tmp//orgt
exlLgQbd.aux))

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 5099 strings out of 480991
 100000,460012 words of node,token memory allocated
 487 words of node memory still in use:
   6 hlist, 2 vlist, 2 rule, 2 glue, 4 kern, 1 glyph, 8 attribute, 51 glue_spec,
 8 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:79,3:32,4:6,5:33,6:2,7:45,8:31,9:59
 22474 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 47 fonts using 4814611 bytes
 44i,7n,40p,239b,122s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,100000s
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf></
usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmex10.pfb></usr/sha
re/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb></usr/share/texl
ive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texm
f-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb>
Output written on orgtexlLgQbd.pdf (1 page, 34227 bytes).

PDF statistics: 31 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 20 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)
```

Here are the relevant latex configs.

```
;; Latex Einstellungen
(setq org-latex-compiler "lualatex")
(setq org-preview-latex-image-directory "~/ltximg/")
(setq org-preview-latex-process-alist '((dvisvgm :programs
                                                 ("lualatex" "dvisvgm")
                                                 :description "dvi > svg"
                                                 :message "you need to install the programs: lualatex and dvisvgm."
                                                 :image-input-type "dvi"
                                                 :image-output-type "svg"
                                                 :image-size-adjust (1.7 . 1.5)
                                                 :latex-compiler ("lualatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
                                                 :image-converter ("dvisvgm %f -n -b min -c %S -o %O")
                                                 )
                                        )
      )
(setq org-latex-default-packages-alist
      '(
        ("" "fontspec" t nil)
        ("" "graphicx" t nil)
        ("" "grffile" t nil)
        ("" "longtable" nil nil)
        ("" "wrapfig" nil nil)
        ("" "rotating" nil nil)
        ("normalem" "ulem" t nil)
        ("" "amsmath" t nil)
        ("" "textcomp" t nil)
        ("" "amssymb" t nil)
        ("" "capt-of" nil nil)
        ("" "hyperref" nil nil)
        ("" "bookmark" nil nil)
        ))

(setq org-preview-latex-default-process 'dvisvgm)
```

I use Emacs 28 with the latest org-mode version on Linux Fedora.

Does anybody know how this possible?

Regards
Poul

Answer (score 1):

`lualatex` seems to produce a PDF. The `dvisvgm` process expected a `dvi` file. Try changing the setting for `dvisvgm` to ("latex" "dvisvgm"). `latex` produces a `dvi` that `dvisvgm` can then consume.

Alternatively, you can ask `lualatex` to produce a `dvi` instead of PDF, by changing the entry to `("lualatex --output-format=dvi" "dvisgvgm")`.

Untested.