# Org-mode LaTeX previews image size too large

Tags: org-mode, latex, preview-latex, org-roam

**SOLVED: REMOVE `#+SETUPFILE:` HEADER. SORRY FOR WASTING YOUR TIME**

I am having the same issue as described in this [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/orgmode/comments/o0l0dn/latex_preview_rendering_has_a_really_large_height/) from a few weeks ago: basically the preview images generated for a given latex fragment in the file are too large **vertically** and make the file unreadable.

I started out using `dvipng` (the default) to generate the images.
I've played around with adding

```
(setq org-format-latex-options (plist-put org-format-latex-options :scale 2.0))
```

to my config: this made the rendered latex larger (which was helpful) but unfortunately did not cut down the size of the images (which in fact got larger).

I've also tried switching form `dvipng` to `dvisvgm`, the latter just gave the error

```
Latex-preview not working; Please adjust ‘dvisvgm’ part of ‘org-preview-latex-process-alist’
```

like in this [post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/63913/latex-preview-not-working-please-adjust-dvisvgm-part-of-org-preview-latex-pr).

Finally, I have also tried the `texfrag` package, which kind of works, but only after setting the scale and generating previews, getting an error, and then generating previews again. It doesn't work with `#+STARTUP: latexpreview`.

**EDIT:**

As requested, here is a brief snippet of an `org-roam` file that produces unwieldy previews:

```
#+title: Kullback-Leibler divergence
#+roam_tags: "machine learning" "statistics" "probability"
* Kullback-Leibler Divergence
For two continuous probability distributions of one dimension $P$ and $Q$, the Kullback-Leibler (KL) divergence, also known as the relative entropy, gives a measure of the difference between them. The definition is as follows:

\begin{eqnarray}
  \label{eq:KL}
  D_Q(P) = \int_{\infty}^{\infty} dx ~ P(x) \log \left(frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} \right) \,, 
\end{eqnarray}

from which we can see that the KL divergence is not symmetric - $D_Q(P)$ is a measure of the divergence of $P$ from $Q$, while $D_P(Q)$ measures the divergence of $Q$ from $P$, and these are in general different.
```

(I don't think `org-roam` has anything to do with this, just a handy example)

**EDIT2:**
Emacs 27.2 and Org mode version 9.4.4

`GNU Emacs 27.2 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.27, cairo version 1.17.4) of 2021-03-26`

`Org mode version 9.4.4 (release_9.4.4 @ /usr/share/emacs/27.2/lisp/org/)`

**EDIT3:**

Here is the current setup of `org-preview-latex-process-alist`:

```
Value:
((dvipng :programs
     ("latex" "dvipng")
     :description "dvi > png" :message "you need to install the programs: latex and dvipng." :image-input-type "dvi" :image-output-type "png" :image-size-adjust
 (1.0 . 1.0)
     :latex-compiler
     ("latex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
     :image-converter
     ("dvipng -D %D -T tight -o %O %f"))
 (dvisvgm :programs
      ("latex" "dvisvgm")
      :description "dvi > svg" :message "you need to install the programs: latex and dvisvgm." :image-input-type "dvi" :image-output-type "svg" :image-size-adjust
      (1.7 . 1.5)
      :latex-compiler
      ("latex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
      :image-converter
      ("dvisvgm %f -n -b min -c %S -o %O"))
 (imagemagick :programs
          ("latex" "convert")
          :description "pdf > png" :message "you need to install the programs: latex and imagemagick." :image-input-type "pdf" :image-output-type "png" :image-size-adjust
          (1.0 . 1.0)
          :latex-compiler
          ("pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
          :image-converter
          ("convert -density %D -trim -antialias %f -quality 100 %O")))
```

Comment: Can you add to your question an Org mode file with some LaTeX that produces such large images? WIthout that, I'm afraid there is not enough information to help you.

Comment: @NickD Done, but the issue is pretty generic. Basically put up the most minimal org headers, then in the body type in `$x=1$` or some longer `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}` block, and the result persists. See also the example given in the linked Reddit post.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it (either with dvipng or imagemagick): the previews are reasonably small. Please try with `emacs -q`  (i.e. without your init file) and see if you can reproduce it. If not, then some setting in your init file is causing this. Also post the version of emacs and Org mode you are using (`M-x emacs-version` and `M-x org-version` resp).

Comment: @NickD `emacs -q` still gives the previews that are oversized (again, the text is correctly sized but the image dimensions are too large)

Comment: @NickD GNU Emacs 27.2 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.27, cairo version 1.17.4) of 2021-03-26
Org mode version 9.4.4 (release_9.4.4 @ /usr/share/emacs/27.2/lisp/org/)

Comment: Forgot to add: please make sure that the `ltximg/` directory is cleaned out before trying: if the images exist already, they will not be regenerated, so you won't know if the problem persists.

Comment: @NickD Thanks, but I tried this on a file without any previous images created, this still created a problem.

Comment: Let's continue on [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127851/discussion-between-nickd-and-nonreligious)

Answer (score 0):

## Table of Contents

1. Test 1
2. Test 2
3. Resolution

The issue described here is a partial resolution of [this post I raised yesterday](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/66817/org-mode-latex-previews-image-size-too-large)

The problem is that LaTeX previews generated from org files I was creating were too large, took very long to process and made the text unreadable due to their size.

After some help from @NickD, I realized that the problem was that I was using a setupfile for LaTeX export for some of the other files in the same folder! But it took a long time to figure out why this was a problem.

I created two files, `test1.org` and `test2.org`. Initially, both contain the same pieces of LaTeX terms, and I placed both in a separate folder. `test1.org` was a standard `.org` file, while `test2.org` included the header for the setup file.

## Test 1

Here is what `test1.org` looked like in raw form:
[image: ![img](./test1-1.png)]

and here is what it looks like after applying previews with `C-c C-x C-l`:

The previews are actually good! They are appropriately scaled in font, and the size of the preview images means they fit inside sentences.

[image]

## Test 2

Here is `test2.org`, where we include the setup file header `#+SETUPFILE: ~/org/latex/latex<sub>template.org</sub>`:
[image: ![img](./test2-1.png)]

Now we apply the previews:

[image: ![img](./test2-2.png)]

This looks exactly the same as `test1.org`! I am not sure, but I believe that `org-latex-preview` must be coded to reuse already generated previews – in this case, I think the previews from `test1.org`, which were previously created, are added to this file.

I added some new LaTeX fragments to `test2.org`:
[image: ![img](./test2-3.png)]

Now, applying the previews, I find that the previous paragraph reuses the same previews as before and appears perfectly fine. But the newly added LaTeX now has previews which are as bad as the initial issue I was having: oversized images which disrupt sentences:
[image: ![img](./test2-4.png)]

[image: ![img](./test2-5.png)]

## Resolution

So I guess what I have to do is to delete all the generated latex previews in my main `org-roam` folder, and remove `#+SETUPFILE: ~/org/latex/latex<sub>template.org</sub>`.

I think the main problem with the size arises from the template requiring `\usepackage{fullpate}` - after removing this the size seems OK, but I haven't done a full check. The other problem of it taking way too long to generate previews still remains.

This is slightly unsatisfactory, as I would like to have the option of both having reasonably sized LaTeX previews, as well as be able to export my notes to a `.pdf` via LaTeX, in the format that I specified. I also have some nice `\newcommand` redefinitions that I am used to using.

Comment: That's why I asked you to post a file that shows the problem - but the file you posted did not contain anything about `#+SETUPFILE`. How do you expect people to help you when you don't give them all the necessary information?

Comment: You can include different LaTeX packages when exporting than when previewing (although the set used for preview is always a subset of the set used for export): use `#+LATEX_HEADER` for packages that you want to include for both previewing and export; use `#LATEX_HEADER_EXTRA` for packages that you want to include for export only.

Comment: @NickD Sorry, but that file was giving me a problem! I didn't realize it was connected to the `#+SETUPFILE` issue until I created a new org file in a new folder. I didn't realize that if you create an preview image from one file, another file could use the same preview image if it has the same symbol!

Comment: But you elided the `#+SETUPFILE` from what you posted: what you posted was *NOT* what you had problems with. Don't do that.

Comment: @NickD It was! This is the key point: What I should have done better I think was delete all the preview images from the folder as you said. I have another file with the same formula in that I had previously generated formulae for (on Autoencoders). This got reused for the preview in the file I posted.